# error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: make, opencv, cmake

I am newbie to Ubuntu.i want to compile a project that uses `opencv`
but it gives following error:

```
cmake . && make
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ground_estimation.dir/projectdir/src/stereo_matching/OpenCvStereo.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv3gpu6GpuMatC1ERKNS_3MatE'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ground_estimation] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ground_estimation.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I also used this command `cmake . && make -lopencv_core` but did not solve.
(Ubuntu 14.04 64bit,OpenCV 2.4.9)

Comment: Is it your own project? did you write the Makefile yourself? It looks like there is some *name mangling* which suggests it is mixing up C and C++ linkage

Comment: no its not mine,its this: https://bitbucket.org/rodrigob/doppia

Comment: I'm also facing a similar problem. What is the reason for this?