# undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: compiling, make, cmake, ld

Similar question has been asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510606/error-adding-symbols-dso-missing-from-command-line) but is unanswered.

I have an implementation of `Levenberg-Marquardt` (downloaded from somewhere) and I'm trying to compile it but getting the following error.

```
gauravloj@vertex:~/Documents/source_code/non-rigid_registration/Gauss_newton/levmar-2.6$ make
[ 87%] Built target levmar
Linking C executable lmdemo
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/lmdemo.dir/lmdemo.c.o: undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lmdemo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lmdemo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

At many sites, the solution given was to add some flags (e.g [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334884/while-compiling-truecrypt-i-get-undefined-reference-to-symbol-dlcloseglibc) and [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-compiling-%27foto%27-%5Berror-adding-symbols-dso-missing-from-command-line%5D-4175493187/)). But none of them worked for me.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/KJEmgVQN) is the Makefile, [here](http://pastebin.com/ppY6p429) is the CMakeLists.txt and [here](http://pastebin.com/kzdUCNfm) is the CMakeCache.txt.

Comment: What is your glibc version?

Comment: `ldd --version` gave `(Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.3) 2.19`.

Comment: Please include your Makefile. This is clearly something with broken library dependencies (and possible glib version mismatches).

Comment: Are you sure you've tried adding `-lm`? Where did you add it?

Comment: @Shashwat: Where exactly did you add this? Can you please post the code? Thanks

Comment: @muru What is `-lm`, exactly?

Comment: @KyleStrand it links the maths library: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4606301/2072269, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've added `-lm` into `CMakeLists.txt` where libraries are being assigned. It's working now.

Comment: Can you show the addition in detail? Thank you

Answer (score 18):

Seems like the user who found the solution never shared it later. For guys who are trying to find the solution just add the math library explicitly and also add `-ldl`

So `-lm` and `-ldl` in the `gcc` line you are compiling and it should go just fine.

Alternatively, in most cases you can also explicitly define `CFLAGS` and alleviate the issue that way. These are just two ways of solving,

Example:

```
user@compiler-shell$ EXPORT CFLAGS=" -g -O2 -lm -ldl -Wall -Wpointer-arith -finline-functions -ffast-math -funroll-all-loops";
```

Comment: I have found the need for `-lm` elsewhere already, but at least in my case the additional `-ldl` was what finally made it work. Cudos for documenting it here!

Answer (score 6):

I found this thread with a similar problem. Explicitly, the solution is to find and change in your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lmdemo ${LIBS})
```

to

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lmdemo -lm ${LIBS})
```